# Please help get started with creating a simple project using eclipse, spring, maven

Tags: java, spring

1. I installed maven and configured based on their 5 minute tutorial
2. Created a eclipse project using Maven
3. Installed Maven Integration for eclipse by going to eclipse market place
4. Added dependencies (spring, log4j) to pom.xml by getting the xml snippet from mvnrepository.com
5. right click on pom.xml and run as Maven Install.

I was not able to use the new jar files immediately, had to do mvn install several times and finally all the jar files are showed up in the project.

what could be the problem?  Is it not updating the class path correctly?

My questions are:

1. Are my steps above correct?
2. I see all the dependent jar files in the main folder.  I want to place these jar files under lib folder.  How do i do that?
3. How can i add external jar file to the repository, these are not in mvnrepository
4. How do i generate ear file to be deployed to weblogic?

Edit: Attached the screenshot of the repository[image: repository]

Edit2: i picked the wrong project type.  Once i picked webapp archetype, it puts all dependencies in "Maven Dependencies".  This is related to my second question.

Comment: question 2: better read some documentation on what maven is about

Comment: You don't manage the dependent jars yourself; Maven and the IDE plugin manage them. Don't move them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For your question 3 :** You can add any public maven repositories in to your pom file which contains your required jar files. 
http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?63612-Maven-repository-location

or else if you have that jar file in your local machine you can manually install it into maven repository.

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=<path-to-file> -DgroupId=group-id  
    -DartifactId=artifact-id -Dversion=version -Dpackaging=packaging
```

As per the [Guide to installing 3rd party JARs](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-local.html).

**For your 2nd question** you can use:

http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/

Comment: Thanks for the tip about adding external jar files.  for the second question, i dont see relevant information in the link you provided.. i will go through the documentation in detail.

Comment: @priceline . See the example section http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/copying-artifacts.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using m2eclipse, be sure to right click on the project, select Maven and then "Update project configuration". That should be enough. I assume that you added the Maven project nature already.

Comment: I have m3e configured in eclipse.  But I dont see "Update project configuration" on the right click of the project or pom file.

Answer (score 0):

After you create project use can use this command

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

then install `m2eclipse` from eclipse marketplace. What I am doing generally is right click eclipse, import/import new maven project and choose my new maven project. Afer import if you dont see your jar folder under Libraries node of project tree, then right click build path/libraries/add class path and choose related folder.

If your library not available in current repository you can use another external repository with below tag: (jboss and java.net repos are very common)

```
<repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>java.net2</id>
            <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus.</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>never</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
                <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                <checksumPolicy>warn</checksumPolicy>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
</repositories>
```